# Joomla: Listing recently modified pages

Tags: joomla

It's easy enough to show recently modified articles, but I need to list page URLs on a Joomla site that have been most recently modified. Is this straightforward? Is there a module for this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the menu manager you can list all the articles in a category.

Check the options `Article Order` -> `Most recent first`

`Date for Ordering` -> `Modification date`

Otherwise you need to search harder for an extension that does that test your programming skills building a module or a new view in com_content which display what you need.

Let me know if this helps.